# How to use backup .sql file to add databse to sql server using C# console application?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I was working on a project where i made a database on sql server 2008 using visual studio 2010 and i took backup of that databse by right clicking on it in sever explorer and selecting "Publish to Provider" that creates a .sql file in my computer that i taken. Previously i formatted my pc and sql server databases are lost, so now i want to use that .sql file to recreate the database with all data, but i don't know how it can be possible.

Something i tried but it created all tables in master database but i want the database of the name i.e. stored in .sql file or specified by me.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create a Database using this,

```
Create Database YOURDBNAME
```

Here, YOURDBNAME = DataBase Name

Then, Open your .sql file write this in First line of the .sql page,

```
Use YOURDBNAME
```

Now press `F5`, all the tables and data will be created and inserted.

Comment: but in output it shown this
(1 row(s) affected) for many times, do this shows i lost some data
please reply.

Comment: that message is the conformation for the rows that are inserted in tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) libraries to manage all aspects of SQL Server.

> SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) is a collection of objects that are designed for programming all aspects of managing Microsoft SQL Server. SQL Server Replication Management Objects (RMO) is a collection of objects that encapsulates SQL Server replication management.

---

From your description, however, this can be overkill. You get simply use [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) (link goes to the free Express edition download), connect to the server, open a new Query Window with your SQL file and run it (F5).

Comment: Is it possible to do the same using command prompt or Visual Studio.
Because i have very slow internet connection and that SSMS file will take atleast 5 hours to me to download. If possible please tell me other ways using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @user1306589 - Not sure this will work, but if you use the Server Explorer and open a new query on the server you need, you may be able to paste the SQL into the Query portion and run it.